# Android Design - Service vs Thread for Networking

Tags: android, networking, sockets, service, activity

I am writing an Android app, finally (yay me) and for this app I need persistant, but user closeable, network sockets (yes, more than one).  I decided to try my hand at writing my own version of an IRC Client.

My design issue however, is I'm not sure how to run the Socket connectivity itself.  If I put the sockets at the Activity level, they keeps getting closed shortly after the Activity becomes non-visible (also a problem that needs solving...but I think i figured that one out)...but if I run a "connectivity service", I need to find out if I can have multiple instances of it running (the service, that is...one per server/socket).  Either that or a I need a way to Thread the sockets themselves and have multiple threads running that I can still communicate with directly (ID system of some sort).

Thus the question: Is it a 'better', or at least more "proper" design pattern, to put the Socket and networking in a service, and have the Activities consume said service...or should I tie the sockets directly to some Threaded Process owned by the UI Activity and not bother with the service implementation at all?  I do know better than to put the networking directly on the UI thread, but that's as far as I've managed to get.

Comment: Not 100% sure but I would imagine that anything owned by the activity would be killed when the Activity object itself is. I'd think that services are the way to go. I haven't needed to work with them myself yet, but maybe you can create several threads in one service? Also probably worth a read if you haven't already seen it: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is `Service` + `Thread`.

Don't put the `socket` in an `Activity`. The `activity` is for UI. It gets recreated when the user rotates the phone. You can run into problems when the user receives a phone call.

Put your sockets in a `Service`. Your activity/activities can bind to the `Service` and use it's methods. Or you can use a [Messenger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html) to communicate between an `Activity` and the `Service`.

`Services` on Android run in the UI thread so in the `Service` you'll need your own thread for the socket communication.

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion (something I haven't yet tried w/Android, but should work).

Try putting a WebView in your main activity (so it won't die when you switch child activities) which includes a full DOM document and a child iframe element. Set the iframe's src attribute to a comet service you define, with a keep-alive header. Push the messages using comet. Works like a charm in chrome. If your back end doesn't support comet, you can set it up manually.